# Error while installing private cocopods library in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods

My podspec as follow,

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'demo'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of demo.'
  s.description      = 'This is a pob library'

  s.homepage         = 'https://mygitrepo.git'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'authorName' => 'authorName@demo.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://mygitrepo.git', :branch =>'dev/demo' , :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.source_files = 'demo/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Example/Pods/testFramework.framework'
end
```

I created own private cocoapods dependency library : [source](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html). I added few Objective-C classes .h/.m and swift file. After that I push my code into git.

XCode build phases as follow,
[image]

I'm getting **.h** file not **.m** or **swift** files.

I added this dependencies in my project in the pod directory but I not getting **.m** and **.swift** files.

Pod structure in the main project as follow,
[image]

**.m** file not found after installing pod dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'`